# Ошибка при записи в std::map<std::string, boost::variant<>>

Tags: c++, boost, map

Создал `map`

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<boost::variant<std::string, int, double>>> outputData;
```

и вектор

```
std::vector<double> ValDbl;
```

и когда пытаюсь записать

```
outputData.insert("123", ValDbl);
```

получаю ошибку `С2664`

> C2664 "std::_Tree_iterator>>
>   std::_Tree,std::allocator>>,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::insert(std::_Tree_const_iterator>>,const
>   std::pair,std::allocator>>>
>   &)": невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "const char [4]" в "const
>   std::_Tree_const_iterator>>"

подскажите что я делаю неправильно? ведь variant<...> автоматически должен выбирать тип.

Comment: Попробуйте `outputData.insert({"123", ValDbl});`.

Comment: `vector<variant<int, double>>` != `vector<double>`. Если бы было `map<string, variant<double, int>>` тогда `insert({ "1", 1 })` сработал бы

Comment: @acade, я так же пытался записать эти вектора `std::vector<std::string> ValStr; std::vector<int> ValInt;` ошибка одна и та же

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, выдает ту же ошибку, но если записывать вот так то ошибки нет `std::map<std::string, std::vector<boost::variant<int, double, std::string>>> tt_test;
tt_test.insert({ "123", {1,2,3,4,6,7} });`

Comment: У `std::map` нет и никогда не было метода `insert` с  параметрами "ключ и данные". Почему и зачем вы это "пытаетесь"?

Comment: @AnT, как это, [есть](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/)

Comment: @DR.zarigan: Где вы там увидели метод с параметрами `(ключ, данные)`? Методы с двумя параметрами по вашей ссылке - это `(позиция, элемент)` и `(итератор, итератор)`. Все.

Comment: @AnT, а если использовать такую запись, то все равно возникает ошибка `outputData[key].push_back(ch);`

Comment: @DR.zarigan Вы все делаете неправильно. Надо понимать, что выбор типа происходит на этапе компиляции (это же шаблоны). Соответственно, если вы где-то объявили `std::vector<double> ValDbl`, а потом используете `outputData.insert("123", ValDbl);` то компилятор просто не сможет вывести окончательный тип вашего изначального контейнера `outputData`. Почитайте внимательней про `boost::variant`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется, вы неправильно понимаете концепцию `boost::variant`.
В вашем случае `std::vector<boost::variant<std::string, int, double>>` будет содержать не значения определенного типа, а значения типов, указанных в `variant`

Т.е. выглядеть это будет так:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

int main ()
{
  typedef boost::variant <std::string, int, double> TVariant;     
  typedef std::vector<TVariant> TVariantVector;
  typedef std::map<std::string, TVariantVector> TMySuperMap;

  std::string key = "123";
  TVariantVector ValDbl;

  TMySuperMap outputData; 
  outputData.insert(TMySuperMap::value_type(key, ValDbl));

  TVariantVector& vec = outputData[key];

  vec.push_back(0.1);
  vec.push_back(1);
  vec.push_back("my_string");

  for (auto& item: vec)
    std::cout << item << std::endl;   

  return 0;
}
```

https://www.onlinegdb.com/BJsquLZ0Q